# USGS Nationalmap API giving error for certain bbox and polygons

Tags: lidar, usgs

I am using USGS national map API (https://tnmaccess.nationalmap.gov/api/v1/products) to search for Lidar data.

But for certain `bbox` and `polygon` this API is giving me error.
Example: https://tnmaccess.nationalmap.gov/api/v1/products?bbox=-72.346709,43.373873,-72.346499,43.373894&datasets=Lidar%20Point%20Cloud%20(LPC)&prodFormats=LAS,LAZ

Error noticed:

```
{errorMessage=[BadRequest] ''>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'' , errorType=Exception, stackTrace=["  File \"\/var\/task\/get_products.py\", line 45, in lambda_handler\n    raise Exception(\"[BadRequest] '{}' \".format(e.args[0]))\n"]}
```

Similar error is observed when I query via UI interface provided by USGS https://apps.nationalmap.gov/tnmaccess/#/product

BBox provided is valid and is in format of `minX, minY, maxX, maxY`.

The same API work fine for most other bbox or polygon values.

I am looking for suggestions on root cause of problem and knowing alternatives to avoid this issue.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to have the error message as text in the body of the Question. Images are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched by others.

Comment: Edited question to include error text instead of image

Comment: Looks like it a server-side python error, the National Map Service Desk can help tnm_help@usgs.gov